# How do I pass a URL to a route?

Tags: 8, routes, uri

I need to send the URL of a Drupal 8 route to a template. I read some documentation on [Drupal API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromRoute/8.2.x), but when I implement this in my module, nothing happens.

My route in my routing file looks like the following.

```
movies.addMovie:
    path: /movies/add/{system}/{id}
    defaults:
        _controller: 'Drupal\movies\Controller\InsertController:addMovie'
        _title: 'Add Movie'
        system: ''
        id: ''
    requirements:
        _permission: 'create movies_movie'
```

This is the code I am using to get the URL from the route.

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
Url::fromRoute('movies.addMovie')
```

When I put the URL in a variable, the code stops when calling `Url::fromRoute()`. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the entire error?

Comment: No errors are thrown. The line is just skipped.

Comment: So you assign a breakpoint and set a variable to the result of that call and nothing happens?

Comment: Indeed. When I place a breakpoint on the call and one after the call, the one after the call is not be hit.

Comment: What is the context of your usage?

Comment: I need to place a url of a custom Drupal page to my twig template.
Found already a way to get the url object. Now how can I generate the url of that object. Everything in that object is empty exepct the routename?

Comment: Looks like you found the twig wrapp function ```url()``` -- you should use that inside twig. If you're set on using ```Url::fromRoute()```, then you probably want to call [Url::toString()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AtoString/8.2.x) on the returned [Url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x) object. Like: ```$url_string = Url::fromRoute('add.movie')->toString();```

Comment: See also [Link::createFromRoute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Link.php/function/Link%3A%3AcreateFromRoute/8.2.x) if you're creating a link element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to generate the url of my route using twig template.

I'm now using the url function of twig to generate the full url to my page:

```
{{ url('movies.addMovie')}}
```

Answer (score 2):

should be:
`InsertController::addMovie`

Needs a double-colon.
Yours is single.